# newly created column shows null values in pyspark dataframe

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to add a column calculating the difference in time between two two timestamp values. In order to do that I first add a column with the current datetime which is define as `current_datetime` here:

```
import datetime
#define current datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
#Getting Current date and time
current_datetime=now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print(now)
```

then I want to add `current_datetime` as column value to the df and calculate the diff

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

productsDF = productsDF\
.withColumn('current_time', when(col('Quantity')>1, current_datetime))\
.withColumn('time_diff',\
    (F.unix_timestamp(F.to_timestamp(F.col('current_time')))) - 
    (F.unix_timestamp(F.to_timestamp(F.col('Created_datetime'))))/F.lit(3600)
)
```

The output however is only null values.

`productsDF.select('current_time','Created_datetime','time_diff').show()`

```
+------------+-------------------+---------+
|current_time|   Created_datetime|time_diff|
+------------+-------------------+---------+
|        null|2019-10-12 17:09:18|     null|
|        null|2019-12-03 07:02:07|     null|
|        null|2020-01-16 23:10:08|     null|
|        null|2020-01-21 15:38:39|     null|
|        null|2020-01-21 15:14:55|     null|
```

the new columns are created with type string and double:

```
 |-- current_time: string (nullable = true)
 |-- diff: double (nullable = true)
 |-- time_diff: double (nullable = true)
```

I tried creating the column with string and literal values just to test, but the output is always `null`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fill a column with `current_datetime`, you are missing the `lit()` function:

```
current_datetime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
productsDF = productsDF.withColumn("current_time", lit(current_datetime))
```

For calculating the time difference between the two `timestamp` columns, you can do:

```
productsDF.withColumn('time_diff',(F.unix_timestamp('current_time') - 
    F.unix_timestamp('Created_datetime'))/3600).show()
```

**EDIT:**

For time difference in hours, days, months, and years, you can do:

```
df.withColumn('time_diff_hours',(F.unix_timestamp('current_time') - F.unix_timestamp('Created_datetime'))/3600)\
    .withColumn("time_diff_days", datediff(col("current_time"),col("Created_datetime")))\
    .withColumn("time_diff_months", months_between(col("current_time"),col("Created_datetime")))\
    .withColumn("time_diff_years", year(col("current_time")) - year(col("Created_datetime"))).show()

+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+--------------+----------------+---------------+
|   Created_datetime|       current_time|   time_diff_hours|time_diff_days|time_diff_months|time_diff_years|
+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+--------------+----------------+---------------+
|2019-10-12 17:09:18|2020-10-15 02:45:49|  8841.60861111111|           369|     12.07743093|              1|
|2019-12-03 07:02:07|2020-10-15 02:45:49|7602.7283333333335|           317|     10.38135529|              1|
|2020-01-16 23:10:08|2020-10-15 02:45:49| 6530.594722222222|           273|      8.94031549|              0|
+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+--------------+----------------+---------------+
```

If you want EXACT time differences, then:

```
df.withColumn('time_diff_hours',(F.unix_timestamp('current_time') - F.unix_timestamp('Created_datetime'))/3600)\
    .withColumn('time_diff_days',(F.unix_timestamp('current_time') - F.unix_timestamp('Created_datetime'))/(3600*24))\
    .withColumn('time_diff_years',(F.unix_timestamp('current_time') - F.unix_timestamp('Created_datetime'))/(3600*24*365)).show()

+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|   Created_datetime|       current_time|   time_diff_hours|    time_diff_days|   time_diff_years|
+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|2019-10-12 17:09:18|2020-10-15 02:45:49|  8841.60861111111| 368.4003587962963|1.0093160514967021|
|2019-12-03 07:02:07|2020-10-15 02:45:49|7602.7283333333335|316.78034722222225|0.8678913622526636|
|2020-01-16 23:10:08|2020-10-15 02:45:49| 6530.594722222222| 272.1081134259259|0.7455016806189751|
+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: thanks, now I have the following output for ```time_diff``` which I achieved before (with much messier code): ```+-------------------+-------------------+--------------------+
|       current_time|   Created_datetime|           time_diff|
+-------------------+-------------------+--------------------+
|2020-10-15 07:11:14|2019-10-12 17:09:18|    1.602302314845E9|
|2020-10-15 07:11:14|2019-12-03 07:02:07|1.6023010759647222E9|
|2020-10-15 07:11:14|2020-01-16 23:10:08|1.6023000038311112E9|``` Can I create the column somehow to show the difference in time (year, month, days etc.)?

Comment: Your code is pretty good. Just remove `F.to_timestamp()` because the fields are already in timestamp as per the question. I added the code to calculate time differences in hours, days, months, and years.